# How to retrieve dynamically generated ids from input type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Currently, I have an array of questions stored in a json file, using this code it will call the questions accordingly with the following script, which is then appended to a div called questions. How do I get the dynamically generated ids of the input types into the changeFont function so that not just the questions but also the inputs would be able to have a change in size

```
<script>
    var array = JSON.parse(arrayQuestions);
    console.log(array);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var question = array[i];
        var questionDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var html = "<form>";
        html = question.question + " <br> ";
        var choices = question.choices;
        for (j = 0; j < choices.length; j++) {
            var choicesOpt = choices[j];
            if (question.type == "radio") {
                html += "<fieldset data-role=\"controlgroup\">";
                html += "<input type=\"radio\" data-theme=\"b\" name=\"" + i + "\" id=\"" + i + choicesOpt + "\" value=\"" + choicesOpt + "\" /><label for=\"" + i + choicesOpt + "\">" + choicesOpt + "</label>";
                html += "</fieldset>";
            } else if (question.type == "checkbox") {
                html += "<fieldset data-role=\"controlgroup\">";
                html += "<input class=\"banana\" type=\"checkbox\" data-theme=\"b\" name=\"" + i + "\" id=\"" + i + choicesOpt + "\" value=\"" + choicesOpt + "\" /><label for=\"" + i + choicesOpt + "\">" + choicesOpt + "</label>";
                html += "</fieldset>";
            } else if (question.type == "textbox") {
                html += "<input class=\"banana\" type=\"text\" data-theme=\"b\"  data-clear-btn=\"true\" name=\"" + i + "\" id=\"" + i + choicesOpt + "\" value=\"" + choicesOpt + "\">";
            } else {
                html += "<textarea name=\"" + i + "\" id=\"" + i + choicesOpt + "\"></textarea>";
            }
            html += "";
        }
        html += "</form>";

        //                html += "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"myFunction()\" value=\"Submit form\"></form>";

        questionDiv.innerHTML = html + "<br>";
        document.getElementById('questions').appendChild(questionDiv);


    }

    //code to change font size

    function changeFont(selectTag) {
        var listValue = selectTag.options[selectTag.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("#" + choicesOpt).style.fontSize = listValue;
    }

    $("#" + choicesOpt).each(function () {
        changeFont(selectTag);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you show the generated html please ??

Comment: var html = "<form>";
html = question.question + " <br> "; you are overwriting the value of html i.e "<form>" will be overwritten do u want that??

Comment: you should use html + = question.question + " <br> "; instead

Comment: is there a way not to overwrite the html?

Comment: and when are you calling the  changeFont(selectTag); ???

Comment: there will be a selector and it can be used to select the fontsize accordingly.

Comment: Add that selector to your question please only then can we find a way to retrieve the IDs, or you will have to save the dynamically generate ids in an array perhaps for each question respectively.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the JSON to allow mocking this up? I would suggest a number of changes, to simplify the whole thing, but without a practical example that will take too long.

Comment: Here's the sample json array  :  var arrayQuestions = '[{"question":"Full Name of Resident","type":"textbox","choices":[""]},{"question":"Residency Year","type":"textbox","choices":[""]}]';